# Request camera access only

Tags: android

My app needs camera access for stills only.
The permissions dialog mentions record video.
Is it possible to only request take pictures permission?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer **No**, Android doesn't allow custom layout for permission dialog

> Your app cannot customize the dialog that appears when you call requestPermissions(). The text in the system permission dialog references a permission group, but this permission grouping is designed for system ease-of-use.

read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)